# Determine who plays next

Tags: php

I have this challenge:

> Two players - "black" and "white" play a game. The game consists of several rounds. If a player wins a turn, he must move again in the next turn. If a player loses a turn, the other player moves in the next turn. Given who played his turn in the previous round and whether he won, determine who is to play in this turn.
>
> Write a `whoseMove` function that takes as input 2 parameters and returns either black or white.

How to do this?

Comment: Welcome to the English version of SO. All questions/comments needs to be in English here. - Bienvenue dans la version anglaise de SO. Toutes les questions / commentaires doivent être en anglais ici. (Google translate)

Comment: What is a turn? what makes someone win or lose? What two parameters are the input? What have you tried? What code do you have?

Answer (score 1):

The first argument (who played in the last turn?) is either:

- "black"
- "white"

The second argument (did that player win?) is either:

- `true`
- `false`

So there are 4 possibilities.

In the case the second argument is `true`, you can just return the player as it was given in the first argument. So that deals with 2 out of 4 possibilities. In the other case, you need to swap the color.

You can use a ternary operator to perform that logic:

```
function whoseMove($player, $didWin) {
    return $didWin ? $player : ($player == "black" ? "white" : "black");
}
```

Written with `if ... else` if is a bit more verbose, but more readable:

```
function whoseMove($player, $didWin) {
    if ($didWin) {
        return $player;
    } else if ($player == "black") {
        return "white";
    } else {
        return "black";
    }
}
```